# add Persian(Arabic) fonts typography to WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, arabic

i am WordPress theme developer and i want to add custom Arabic/Persian fonts in my themes options panel typography but i don't want to use Google web fonts because it don't support Arabic fonts how can i add this to my themes panel php?

Comment: You're not showing your code for theme options (the **minimum** to reproduce the problem) and not explaining what do you want exactly: frontend preview, backend dropdown?? For my own reference, how would you load *custom fonts* in a normal HTML? Please :), [edit] your question to clarify and read the guide [ask].

Answer (score 1):

[add Persian(Arabic) fonts typography to WordPress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582916/add-persianarabic-fonts-typography-to-wordpress-theme)

Luckily Google started adding Arabic (and other) web fonts, but they are available in [Early Access](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) section.

For example, you use the following fonts:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/amiri.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/dhyana.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabicnaskh.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lateef.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/scheherazade.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/thabit.css);
```

then use in your css styling:

```
font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
font-family: 'Dhyana', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh', serif;
font-family: 'Lateef', serif;
font-family: 'Scheherazade', serif;
font-family: 'Thabit', serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to PLUGINS.
2. Add new plugin called Arabic **Webfonts**.
3. Activate this Plugin.
4. Go to your website and click **Customize**.
5. You will see the newly Added plugin (arabic webfonts).
6. Select Whatever you want (Heading, body...).
7. Select The Font family you want from the dropdown list.
8. Enjoy it.